# How to convert Buffer to string and string to buffer in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to write universal function that work with Buffer and with string. I'm not able to get the same buffer after I converted it to string.

```
fs.readFile(process.argv[2], function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        var text = data.toString('ascii');
        var buff = Buffer.from(text);
        console.log(ansilove.sauceBytes(data));
        console.log(ansilove.sauceBytes(buff));
    }
});
```

I'm using library from GitHub [ansilove.js](https://github.com/nvdnkpr/ansilove.js) (the original seems to get removed. And it's also not on npm).

the problem is that when I parse [SAUCE](http://www.acid.org/info/sauce/sauce.htm) meta data, I've got 160 as tInfo1, but after I convert buffer to string and back to buffer I've got 32. This also the output I've got for my previous code when I was parsing strings (not like ansilove  uint8array).

I've also tried:

```
    var text = data.toString('ascii');
    var buff = Buffer.from(new TextEncoder('utf8').encode(text));
    var buff = Buffer.from(new TextEncoder('ascii').encode(text));
    var buff = new Uint8Array(new TextEncoder('ascii').encode(text));
```

the files are encoded in CP437 but the SAUCE data is not encoded you don't need conversion, it's binary data.

The file I'm testing this against is *tk-machine.ans* from [Fuel27](https://16colo.rs/pack/fuel27/) pack (you need to download zip file).

Comment: @Blastfurnace the original code that was reading the SAUCE records was in C, I've modified the question few times, previous question was how to read unsign long in JavaScript like in C.

Comment: "*the files are encoded in CP437*" - then don't use `utf8` or `ascii` for decoding them?!

Comment: When using ascii (or even utf8) each byte is getting [turned into a signed int](https://github.com/feross/buffer/blob/master/index.js#L1048). At least if that Buffer recreation is accurate to the actual nodejs internal code, which it seems to be as getting that specific byte will give you `32` (from text) instead of `160` (from data), and `160 & 0x7F = 32`. If you use an encoding like `binary` that doesn't happen. Closest Nodejs code I found was [this](https://github.com/openwebos/nodejs/blob/master/src/node_buffer.cc#L251) which has Encode vs String::New for binary vs ascii